# How to calculate a pair address given token addresses

Tags: addresses, hash

How do you combine two token addresses to form a pair address?

I would imagine this is purely mathematical and doesn't require a call to web3.  I want to know how to do it without calling the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about uniswap v2 or v3 here? In both cases, you can take a look at the uniswap contracts directly and figure it out. Just translate the code to any language you're comfortable with. For v2, you'll find the implementation [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L18),
for v3, [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/PoolAddress.sol)

Comment: Thanks but how about the other way around?

Comment: What do you mean? Getting the token addresses from the pair address? You can't do that (well, i guess theorically its possible, you'd just have to crack keccak)